# ffmpeg, replace part of audio in mp4 video file

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to replace part of the audio in one mp4 file with part of another mp3 file using ffmpeg. 
this is what I'm trying to do:

```
ffmpeg -i 2009.mp4 -i birds.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]atrim=end=45,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aud1];[1:a]atrim=0:18,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aud2];  [0:a]atrim=start=63,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aud3]; [aud1][aud2][aud3]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[aout]"  -map 0:v -map "[aout]" -c:v copy   output.mp4
```

it is giving me this error:

> [NULL @ 000000000596e020] Unable to find a suitable output format for
>   'ffmpeg' ffmpeg: Invalid argument

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem, and now everything is working fine. 
I wanted to replace the first 60 seconds of audio in mp4 file with another mp3 file, and fade out that audio in the last 3 seconds. The correct code is:

```
 -y -i  C:\videotemp\temp.mp4 -i intro-mpdified.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]atrim=start=60,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aud1];[1:a]atrim=0:60,afade=t=out:st=57:d=3,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aud2];  [aud2][aud1]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[aout]"  -map 0:v -map "[aout]" -c:v copy -c:a  libmp3lame C:\videotemp\tempnew.mp4
```